# Синхронизировать карту Map

Tags: многопоточность, java, concurrency, synchronized

Доброго дня.
Есть некий класс:

```
public class T {
    private Map myMap;
    public Object findInMap(Object key) {
        //operations
    }
    public void rewriteData(Object data){
        //operations
       myMap.clear();
       myMap.putAll(newMap);
    }
}
```

Есть множество потоков, которые получают доступ к методу `findInMap`, который берет данные из карты `myMap` по индексу ну и кое-что делает с ними еще и возвращает.
Иногда данные карты полностью перезаписываются. Делается это так:

```
myMap.clear();
myMap.putAll(newMap);
```

Вопрос: как недопустить доступ к карте в тот момент, когда программа находится на момент, когда карта стала очищена, но в нее еще не успели записаться все данные методом `putAll`?

Comment: используйте ConcurrentMap    
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html

Comment: @Andreich не подойдет в силу требований в конце вопроса.

Comment: В каждый метод добавить по syncronized.

Comment: @Deadkenny ну не эффективно же!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкурентный доступ на чтение из множества потоков синхронизировать не нужно, т.к. в вашем случае большую часть времени Map не изменяется.

В зависимости от ваших потребностей можно пойти двумя путями.

Использовать новый экземпляр Map при заполнении.

```
private volatile Map map;

public Object findInMap(Object key) {
    Map localCopy = map; //volatile read 
    //operations via localCopy
}

public void rewriteData(Object data) {
    Map newMap = new HashMap();
    //fill new map
    map = newMap;  // volatile write
}
```

Вместо volatile можно использовать [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

Использовать один экземпляр Map и [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

```
private Map map = new HashMap();
private ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public Object findInMap(Object key) {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        //operations
     } finally {
         lock.readLock().unlock()
     }
}

public void rewriteData(Object data) {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        map.clear();
        map.putAll(...);
    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: @a_gura: Хм. По первому пути: формально решение правильное, но: какова _семантика_ найденного объекта? Вы _не можете_ гарантировать его осмысленность, т. к. map может поменяться сразу после строки `Map localCopy = map;`. То есть семантика найденного значения — «какое-то значение в какой-то неопределённый момент в прошлом», не слишком-то привлекательно.

Я за классический lock.

Comment: @VladD Потому я и говорю, что это зависит от потребностей. Первый вариант может использоваться например при кэшировании, когда точно известно, что возврат устаревшего значения не ведёт к негативным последствиям и является предпочтительным по сравнению с увеличением времени ответа.

Comment: @a_gura Спасибо за такой прекрасный ответ! Для меня первый способ хорошо подходит, потому что карта выступает в виде кэша.

Comment: @VladD а вы можете привести пример, когда «какое-то значение в прошлом» не будет нас устраивать? Ведь если сравнить предложенный вами «плохой» сценарий с выполнением этих же операций в утопической модели  (где можно считать, что все операции выполняются атомарно), то схема 

 1. сняли localCopy = map
 2. «сразу после» map поменялась в результате `rewriteData()`
 3. на основании устаревшего `localCopy` вернули «плохой» результат

не будет ничем отличаться от

 1. атомарно выполнили `findInMap()`
 2. атомарно выполнили `rewriteData()`

Comment: @VladD Конкретный пример привести не могу. Я обычно сталкивался как раз с тем, что устаревшие значения приемлемы (просто иногда требуется дополнительная функциональность для клиента этого значения). Можно пофантазировать, но кажется, что это неблагодарное занятие.

Есть случаи, когда нужно минимизировать вероятность получения старого значения. Тогда имеет смысл использовать lock и блокировать все читающие потоки. В системе раздачи контента это имеет смысл, т.к. если вернуть клиенту старое значение, с которым он будет отправлен на раздающий сервер, то будет ошибка, т.к. контента уже нет.

Comment: @Jofsey: Сумма на счету?

Comment: @VladD я почему-то считал, что `rewriteData()` подразумевает полную перезапись, а не новое значение на основании предыдущего. Но об этом уже не стоит спорить.

А вот если добавить блокировку на запись, то любые кейсы пройдут корректно.

Comment: @Jofsey: В любом случае, какая бы ни была семантика у `rewriteData()` (полная перезапись или нет), устаревшее значение для текущей суммы на банковском счету — не самая хорошая идея. Представьте себе, что идёт запрос на снятие большой суммы денег.

Comment: @VladD Если мы просто показываем сумму, то ничего страшного. Когда пойдет реальное списание например, операция не должна идти в кэш (а по хорошему даже должна инвалидировать это значение), а транзакция по счету не должна пройти.

Comment: @VladD знали бы вы [какую гору текста я написал ответом на ваш предыдущий вариант комментария](http://pastie.org/private/5o5qv3wkiwap4qlxhtysw) :)

А на счёт транзакций — это уже не зона ответственности нашего объекта, там понадобятся дополнительные блокировки.

Comment: @a_gura: **Если.** А если это уже и есть списание? Модель не имеет права думать за бизнес-логику.

Я не про использование для кеша, что вы. С кешем устаревшее значение не так трагично.

Comment: @VladD в общем, мне кажется, мы просто спорим об условиях. Давайте не будем.

Comment: @Jofsey: Вы правы в том, что **оба** подхода не будут правильно работать для такой операции, как снятие денег со счёта. Это говорит лишь о том, что **бессмысленно** определять синхронизации в терминах структуры данных, нужно опираться её использование, семантику верхнего уровня. В частности, для суммы на банковском счету ВСЯ большая составная операция «проверить доступность суммы, снять сумму, записать обновлённое значение» должна выполняться под одной общей блокировкой.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой, но не очень правильный вариант — брать блокировку на весь объект

```
public class T {
    private Map myMap;
    public  synchronized Object findInMap(Object key) {
        //operations
    }
    public synchronized void rewriteData(Object data){
        //operations
       myMap.clear();
       myMap.putAll(newMap);
    }
}
```

Более эффективным способом будет брать блокировку только непосредственно в момент операций с мапой, а вычисления производить параллельно.

```
public class T {
    private final Map myMap = new HashMap();
    public Object findInMap(Object key) {
        //precomputations
        synchronized (myMap) {
           //map operations
       }
    }
    public void rewriteData(Object data){
        //operations
       synchronized (myMap) {
           myMap.clear();
           myMap.putAll(newMap);
       }
    }
}
```

А ещё лучше используйте copy-on-write или ReadWriteLock, как предложил [[@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura)](/users/1439/a_gura)

Comment: @Jofsey дорогое решение. Copy-on-write тоже не подойдет, т.к. будет существовать момент, в который мэпка окажется пустой (между вызовами clear и putAll).

Comment: @a_gura вызовы clear и putall это не copy-on-write. Copy-on-write это то что вы предложили в качестве первого варианта. На него я и ссылался.

Comment: @Jofsey Семантика copy-on-write в java.util.concurrent - это вовсе не то, что я предложил в первом варианте. Разница в том, что в моем случае, все потоки будут всегда читать данные из старого экземпляра не блокируясь, пока его не подменят. В случае copy-on-write коллекции, все потоки будут заблокированы на время копирования данных. Разница, на мой взгляд, существенная.

Comment: @Jofsey Ан нет, я ошибаюсь. Сорри. Но именно со случаем `clear` и `putAll` действительно остается возможность нарваться на пустую коллекцию в реализациях `CopyOnWriteArrayList` и `CopyOnWriteArraySet`.